# How do I load data into a unit test using the [AssemblyInitialize] or [ClassInitialize] attributes and still have the data persist

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, unit-testing

I know I'm missing one important rule about static methods but would would be the point of initializing something if you couldn't' use it later on for different purposes?

I have a method called LoadValidConfig and a private member called configSetup

```
     [TestClass]
     public class ConfigControllerTest
     {
      private ConfigSetup configSetup;
      private TestContext testContextInstance;

           [ClassInitialize]
           public static void LoadValidConfig(TestContext context)
           {
                ConfigSetup setup;
                ConfigController.LoadConfig(out setup);
           }

           [TestMethod]
           public void ConfigTest1()
           { 
            //example test
           }
    }
```

I can't get the static method to access and initialize the configSetup class with the ConfigSetup reference populated by the ConfigController.LoadConfig() method.

I could really use some direction here. I've used N Unit in the past to do [setup] and [teardown] initialization and cleanup respectively before but this isn't working like those.

Comment: You know you are never writing to the configSetup variable, right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[ClassInitialize]` runs in a static context and is run *before any of the test methods run*. You are probably looking for `[TestInitialize]` which is for an instance initialization method, and is similar to NUnit's `[Setup]`.

Then try assigning your field after the LoadConfig method:

```
[TestInitialize]
public void LoadValidConfig()
{
    ConfigSetup setup;
    ConfigController.LoadConfig(out setup);
    configSetup = value;
}
```

(Or, you could keep ClassInitialize if that suits you better, and make configSetup static).

Comment: What if the same setup is required for multiple tests? Wouldn't the [TestInitialize] be redundant as it would be loading the same data?